# Jquery slideshow внешняя ссылка во фрагменте

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Здравствуйте. Использую готовый jquery plugin для slider'a контента. Вот часть кода:

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
  <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-1">
    <a href="#fragment-1"> <span>Patients</span> </a> 
  </li>
    .
    .
    .
</ul>
```

В атрибуте указан якорь на блок контента, а необходимо чтобы помимо этого, при нажатие на ссылку, осуществлялся переход на указанную страницу. Если ли способ это как-нибудь сделать?

Comment: Что-то понять не могу. Вы, как я понял, используете [виджет UI Tabs][1], который позволяет без перезагрузки переходить по закладкам с разным контентом. Тогда вопрос - а зачем же вам перезагрузка?

   [1]: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: я использую http://demo.webdeveloperplus.com/featured-content-slider/
он сам переключается по якорям. Но мне нужно чтобы ПОМИМО этого при нажатии на ссылку, открывалась другая страница.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Но мне нужно чтобы ПОМИМО этого при
> нажатии на ссылку, открывалась другая
> страница

Угу, а со слайдером что делать? В общем, видать сегодня день такой - день неадекватных задач.

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
  <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-1">
    <a href="some_page_1.html#fragment-1"> <span>Patients</span> </a> 
  </li>
  <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-2">
    <a href="some_page_2.html#fragment-2"> <span>Doctors</span> </a> 
  </li>
  <li class="ui-tabs-nav-item ui-tabs-selected" id="nav-fragment-3">
    <a href="some_page_3.html#fragment-3"> <span>Diagnosis - lamer</span> </a> 
  </li>
    .
    .
    .
</ul>
```

Comment: слайдер пусть работает/крутится.
К сожалению, ваш вариант не работает.

Comment: Так вам надо не переходить по ссылке на другую страницу, а подгружать её. В это случае, смотрите в сторону Ajax. Например, метод [.load()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_HTML-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85). И код будет примерно так выглядеть:    $("#container").load("path_to_page/page.html");Где #container - это id блока, в который надо подгружать страницу

Comment: Спасибо, что пытаетесь мне помоч, но дело в том, что мне не нужно никуда ничего подгружать, а необходимо реализовать именно переход, как по обычной гиперсылке, на другую страницу. 
Я прекрасно понимаю, что это, по крайней мере для меня, из разряда невозможных вещей, поэтому я и спрашиваю "а возможно ли это вообще реализовать?".